# Changing height of a div in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html

I want to use jQuery to change the height of all `div` tags with a particular `class`.
I have successfully set the height using CSS, but I want to change it from jQuery.

I have tried the following code:

```
  $('.slide-container').css({ "height": 200 + "px !important" }); 
  $('.slide-container').height(200);
  $('.slide-container').css({ "height": 200 + "px" });
```

This is the CSS which sets the original height.

```
.slide-container {     height:300px !important; }
```

[Here is a JSFiddle of my attempts.](http://jsfiddle.net/kv4Fb/1/)

Comment: Why does your question title have `c#` then?

Comment: Why do you set `!important` in your class declaration? You should really never use that unless you know what you are doing…

Comment: @user1167870 Did any of the answers provided help you out?

Answer (score 0):

JQuery has a built in function to set height.

http://api.jquery.com/height/

```
$('.slide-container').height(200);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="slide-container">
    apply height to a div tag ,that div is generating from 
    jquery with some class, when height comes from database!
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">

    var newHeight = yourHeightFromDB;
    $(function() {
        $('.slide-container').height(newHeight);
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line in css

`height: 300px !important;`

to

`height: 300px;`

This statement is basically not allowing you to set the height dynamically.
`Your Jquery code is working fine.`

else can for this code as well

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

      $('.slide-container').height(500);
  });
```